# Autoincrement sequence number of element related to group. Spring App

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, psql

I have the next problem:

My DB table has 2 params, a group, and a sequence number. I have to count the sequence number of each element in the group beginning from 1.
It should look like:

```
group   |   sequence
gr1     |      1
gr1     |      2
gr1     |      3
gr1     |      4
gr2     |      1
gr2     |      2
gr3     |      1
gr3     |      2
gr3     |      3
```

I don't want to call db for every save getting the last element of the group and increment it in code because of concurrency issues, instead, I want to make db do this by itself.
Is there any way to do this using Spring, Hibernate, or even psql script?

I've found this answer: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59654671/spring-data-jpa-entities-with-composite-key-in-which-one-column-is-an-internal) but I don't understand how to use this trigger. Thanks.

DB - Postgress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any info about this, so my conclusion is that currently, it's impossible.
But we can create a View where we will group them by `sequence` instead.
Yes, we don't make DB understand our groups, and resolve sequences, but we can organize those groups with sequences in run time instead.